# How to modify a Google Sheets script to highlight cells for date repeats and display a warning?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I modify the provided Google Sheets script to highlight cells in red when there is a repeat on a date in the "MINHA VIDA E MINISTÉRIO CRISTÃO_2022" sheet for names in cells B29:H42 on the "PARTES MECÂNICAS & PREGAÇÃO_2022" sheet? Additionally, how can I display a warning message indicating that there is a repeated name in the specified cells if applicable? Are there any specific syntax or formatting requirements that need to be followed when modifying the script?

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0DPR6TspOZiW2E51tg5S0C771Ts7nP8RK8NuTrPeYs/edit?usp=sharing/)

```
function destacarNomesRepetidos() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const abaOrigem = ss.getSheetByName("MINHA VIDA E MINISTÉRIO CRISTÃO_2022");
  const abaDestino = ss.getSheetByName("PARTES MECÂNICAS & PREGAÇÃO_2022");

// Get data from the source and destination worksheet
  const dadosOrigem = abaOrigem.getRange("A2:H").getValues();
  const dadosDestino = abaDestino.getRange("B29:H42").getValues();
  const rangeDestino = abaDestino.getRange("B29:H42");

// Set for storing repeated names
  const nomesRepetidos = new Set();

  // Loop through the rows of the source worksheet
  dadosOrigem.forEach((linhaOrigem, indiceLinha) => {
    // Get the row date
    const data = linhaOrigem[0];
    if (data !== "") {
      // Get line name and availability times
      const nome = linhaOrigem[1];
      const horarios = linhaOrigem.slice(2);

      // Find the lines in the destination with the same date and times
      const linhasDestino = dadosDestino.reduce((acumulador, linhaDestino, indiceLinhaDestino) => {
        const horariosDestino = linhaDestino.slice(1);
        if (linhaDestino[0] === data && horarios.every((horario, indice) => horario === horariosDestino[indice])) {
          acumulador.push(indiceLinhaDestino);
        }
        return acumulador;
      }, []);

      // If there is more than one row in the destination with the same date and times, mark the corresponding cells in red
      if (linhasDestino.length > 1) {
        nomesRepetidos.add(nome);
        linhasDestino.forEach(indiceLinhaDestino => {
          rangeDestino.getCell(indiceLinhaDestino + 1, 1).setBackground("red");
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // If there are repeated names, display an alert message
  if (nomesRepetidos.size > 0) {
    const mensagem = `Nomes repetidos na coluna A: ${Array.from(nomesRepetidos).join(", ")}.`;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(mensagem);
  } else {
// Otherwise, clear the background color of the cells
    rangeDestino.setBackground(null);
  }
}
```

The given script receives data from two sheets and identifies if there are repeated names in both sheets. If there are repeated names, it highlights the corresponding cells in red and displays an alert message indicating which names are being repeated. The goal is to modify the script to highlight in red the cells where there is a repeat on a date in the "MINHA VIDA E MINISTÉRIO CRISTÃO_2022" sheet for names in cells B29:H42 on the "PARTES MECÂNICAS & PREGAÇÃO_2022" sheet and display a warning message indicating that there is a repeated name in the specified cells.

I have changed the entire spreadsheet to make it easier to understand. Note that there are rows in the spreadsheet that are highlighted in blue. I want the script to check only the rows that are highlighted in blue to see if there are any repeated names with the date in the "A1" tab in the following columns: "CONFERÊNCIA PÚBLICA - Central Águas Claras", "DATA", "PRESIDENTE", "ORADOR", "LEITORES DE A SENTINELA - Central Águas Claras", "LEITOR", "PARTES MECÂNICAS - Central Águas Claras", "1º", "2º", "DIREITA", "ESQUERDA", "AUDIO", "VIDEO". In tab "A2", in the blue columns: "PRESIDENTE:", "TESOUROS DA PALAVRA DE DEUS", "FAÇA SEU MELHOR NO MINISTÉRIO", "NOSSA VIDA CRISTÃ". Note that the name "Ewerton Martins" is highlighted in red. I highlighted it in red because on the date 12/02/2023, the name "Ewerton Martins" was repeated in the "A1" tab in rows and columns highlighted in blue. It was also repeated in the "A2" tab in rows and columns highlighted in blue. I would like the script to highlight the background in red and inform the user that the repeated name is in the cells and tabs. In this example: it is in several cells and it is also in tabs A1 and A2. I hope that explaining it in as much detail as possible has been helpful.

Comment: Have you review the option to use the conditional format rules to highlight them based on the criteria being met: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't, I just failed.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, how many questions are included in your question?

Comment: @Tanaike you can join the chat, it's easier?

Comment: @Tanaike I changed and explained in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detailed logic of `The given script receives data from two sheets and identifies if there are repeated names in both sheets.`?

Comment: Example: "Tanaike" will work, play soccer, travel, swim, and give an English lesson on February 12th, 2023. "Tanaike" cannot do multiple things. He can only do one thing. "Ewerton Martins" was just an example. This spreadsheet will have multiple names. Do you understand?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the logic of `The given script receives data from two sheets and identifies if there are repeated names in both sheets.`. I apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: I'll help you understand better. I made some changes to the spreadsheet to make it easier to understand. The rule is simple: each date can only have one name associated with it. If the user enters a second name that already appears on the same date, the script will change the background color to red. This should quickly identify when there are duplicate names on the same date.